# Android Best way to manage SQLite operations

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have a local SQLLite databases. I read a lot of things/stacks posts, but I don't succeed to understand what is the best way to manage sql queries.

Indeed I don't want to do CRUD operations in the UIThread. So to avoid it, and manage queries in another thread, I created a asynctask for this because I can have a lot of queries to do, and it can take times. But I'm not sure it's the best way for that. Asynctask it's generally used when we want to have a link with the UI thread (for a "update"/"insert" query, I don't want to do something in the UIthread, only when I retrieve datas from DB), and I'm not sure it's the best component in terms of performance because all asynctasks are running on one thread, sequentially. (I know there is a way to execute these parallely, but bad perfs)

I saw a lot of Android components as AsyncQueryLoader, LoaderManager, etc but all of these concepts seems to be link to a contentprovider/contentresult. I have only a sqlite database.

So what is the best way to manage all CRUD operations in another thread ? HandlerThread maybe ?

Comment: so [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/1b7201afdf1225c1c37cc6fcae65b5fb/raw/449e01fef7168ca3bb1071d539aed7d2fa841b61/BaseAsyncQueryHandler.java) is a base abstract class that uses such `HandlerThread` - it is a modified `AsyncQueryHandler` that does not require a `ContentProvider`

Comment: Ok but can you explain why is it better than a asynctask or other component ?

Comment: because it has built in CRUD api see `start*()` methods - all you need is to override `do*()` methods (and `on*()` methods if you need the notifications on the UI thread)

Comment: Ok I saw it, but why is it better than a asynctask doing the same thing ? We can do something similar in a asynctask. So is it better in terms of performance or other thing? I just want to understand, in this case, which component is better and for which reasons.

Comment: sure you can do the same even in a `new Thread`.. do you like to write boilerplate code again and again? `AsyncTask` uses a `Thread` under the hood, so does `HandlerThread`, so there is really no difference

Comment: Mhhh ok ok, but if I understand correctly a HandlerThread can execute code in another thread than another HandlerThread, whereas the asynctask will runs all asynctasks on the same thread, right ? (so it can be a reason to choose handlerthread, to avoid to have a lots of tasks in the same thread)

Comment: ok `AsyncTask` uses now `ThreadPoolExecutor` see details [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#208)

Comment: Yes I tried to use "executeOnExecutor", but when I use it, there are lags on the UI... I think it's not the best solution when there are a lots of tasks to execute, isn't it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158065/discussion-between-develost-and-pskink).

Answer (score -1):

You can use RxJava Observable For example:

```
 @Override
public Observable<List<Model>> getModels() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Model>> subscriber) {
            try {
               // select from db and return list
                subscriber.onNext(//your list);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(new RepositoryException(e));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and then

```
return getModels().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use OMR library its provide very easy way to manage SQLite operations.[Reference](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)